# 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas data-frame with a column with float numbers. I tried to split each item in a column by dot '.'. Then I want to add first items to second items. I don't know why this sample code is not working.

```
data= 
0     28.47000
1     28.45000
2     28.16000
3     28.29000
4     28.38000
5     28.49000
6     28.21000
7     29.03000
8     29.11000
9     28.11000

new_array = []
df = list(data)
for i in np.arange(len(data)):
    df1 = df[i].split('.')
    df2 = df1[0]+df[1]/60
    new_array=np.append(new_array,df2)
```

Comment: `data` is `Series` ? `print (type(data))
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.modf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.modf.html) with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
arr = np.modf(data.values)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':data, 'b':arr[1] + arr[0] / 60})
print (df)
       a          b
0  28.47  28.007833
1  28.45  28.007500
2  28.16  28.002667
3  28.29  28.004833
4  28.38  28.006333
5  28.49  28.008167
6  28.21  28.003500
7  29.03  29.000500
8  29.11  29.001833
9  28.11  28.001833
```

**Detail**:

```
arr = np.modf(data.values)
print(arr)
(array([ 0.47,  0.45,  0.16,  0.29,  0.38,  0.49,  0.21,  0.03,  0.11,  0.11]), 
 array([ 28.,  28.,  28.,  28.,  28.,  28.,  28.,  29.,  29.,  28.]))

print(arr[0] / 60)
[ 0.00783333  0.0075      0.00266667  0.00483333  0.00633333  0.00816667
  0.0035      0.0005      0.00183333  0.00183333]
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':data, 'b':arr[1] + arr[0]*5/3 })
print (df)
       a          b
0  28.47  28.783333
1  28.45  28.750000
2  28.16  28.266667
3  28.29  28.483333
4  28.38  28.633333
5  28.49  28.816667
6  28.21  28.350000
7  29.03  29.050000
8  29.11  29.183333
9  28.11  28.183333
```

Comment: still I am getting error like: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @bikuser - oops, I was wrong, there was no strings, but floats. So need numpy function `modf`, because not exist in pandas.

Comment: calculation seems strange, like first items should be 28.7833 why we have 28.007833?

Comment: but the first array should be 47 not 0.47. how to get absolute number?

Comment: @bikuser - hmm, so need multiple by `100` and divide by `60`? like last edit?

Comment: yes I guess pd.DataFrame({'a':data, 'b':arr[1] + arr[0] / 0.6})

Comment: Do you think `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':data, 'b':arr[1] + arr[0]*10/6 })` or `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':data, 'b':arr[1] + arr[0]*5/3 })` ?

Comment: pd.DataFrame({'a':data, 'b':arr[1] + arr[0]*5/3 }) that one is also giving the same answer that I was looking for : . Thank you for your time :)

Comment: @bikuser - Glad can help!

Answer (score 1):

Your data types are floats, not strings, and so cannot be .split() (*this is a string method*). Instead you can look to use math.modf to 'split' a float into fractional and decimal parts 
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/math.html

```
import math

def process(x:float, divisor:int=60) -> float:
"""
Convert a float to its constituent parts. Divide the fractional part by the divisor, and then recombine creating a 'scaled fractional' part,
"""
    b, a = math.modf(x)
    c = a + b/divisor
    return c

df['data'].apply(process)

Out[17]: 
0    28.007833
1    28.007500
2    28.002667
3    28.004833
4    28.006333
5    28.008167
6    28.003500
7    29.000500
8    29.001833
9    28.001833
Name: data=, dtype: float64
```

Your other option is to convert them to strings, split, convert to ints and floats again, do some maths and then combine the floats. I'd rather keep the object as it is personally.